# How to merge two pdf's, one created with wicked_pdf and second through paperclip upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, wicked-pdf

I created a pdf through wicked_pdf gem, now i want to merge two pdf's in one, one created with wicked_pdf and other one uploaded by paperclip in database.

Comment: how you passed paperclip pdf to CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **combined_pdf** gem

**gem install combine_pdf**

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file1.pdf") # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf")
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```

Otherwise, if you want to do the above code in one line

```
(CombinePDF.load("file1.pdf") << CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf") << CombinePDF.load("file3.pdf")).save("combined.pdf")
```

Comment: How can we convert paperClip instance to pdf and pass in CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf")?

Comment: @KunalVashist Can you give some more detail by adding some code or providing gitlink

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdf merge gem.

```
# Gemfile.rb
gem 'rjb'
gem 'pdf-merger'
```

and then :

```
require "pdf/merger"
failure_list = []
pdf = PDF::Merger.new
pdf.add_file "foo.pdf"
pdf.add_file "bar.pdf"
pdf.add_javascript "this.print(true);"
pdf.save_as "combined.pdf", failure_list
```

You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/paulschreiber/pdf-merger).